# Which font is used in "Notices of the AMS"?

Tags: fonts, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

I like the font in "What is ...?" of Notices of the AMS. For instance see this document http://www.ams.org/notices/201005/rtx100500608p.pdf. Does somebody know the name of this font? Is it free?

Comment: If you look at the properties of the PDF (e.g. File->Properties->Fonts), the names of the fonts are there. LucidaBright/Italic/Demi/Smallcaps-Demi LucidaNewMath/Italic/Symbol/Extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is [Lucida Bright](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype-imaging/lucida-bright). It is not free.